# Integral involving Bessel's function, $J_0(ur)$ and $1-r^2$

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I am trying to show that,

\begin{align} \label{eq:q1main}
g(u) = \int_0^1 (1-r^2) J_0(ur)\,\mathrm{d}r = \frac{2}{u^2}J_2(u)
\end{align}

Bessel's function of first kind with zero degree is:

\begin{align*}
J_0(ur) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos(ur\sin\phi)\,\mathrm{d}\phi
\end{align*}

Substitute and evaluate first wrt $r$.

\begin{align*}
g(u)
&=
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 (1-r^2) \int_0^\pi \cos(ur\sin\phi)\,\mathrm{d}\phi \,\mathrm{d}r \\
&=
\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(u\sin\phi)+u\sin\phi\cos(u\sin\phi)}{u^3\sin^3\phi} \,\mathrm{d}\phi \\
\end{align*}

I know that,

\begin{align*}
J_2(u) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos(2\phi-u\sin\phi)\,\mathrm{d}\phi
\end{align*}

but I cannot show the relation.